# why use authentication token instead of session_id for app(android side) in REST API

Tags: java, php, android, api, rest

**in normal php web application** after login we use session_id that came from web browser to check if user loged in or not.

**But in REST API authentication** I read some tutorials that say that php should send back authentication "token" for android app to save it and give it back to php server for every request.

**my question is** why should I send back some authentication token instead of session_id? I can send back session_id by android app and do normal session stuff on php server side.

ps. if my question is not clear tell then I explain more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, REST API should be stateless, it's one of its defining characteristics. You can use session id, but it wouldn't be REST anymore since you'll be operating a client state on server side.